# How can I troubleshoot 'Timeout in initializing connection' error when running my Python script for simulating flight using dronekit API?

Tags: connection, timeout, dronekit-python, initializing

I got a `APIException: Timeout in initializing connection` error when running my Python script for simulating flight using dronekit API.

```
WARNING:dronekit:Link timeout, no heartbeat in last 5 seconds
ERROR:dronekit.mavlink:Exception in MAVLink input loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dronekit/mavlink.py", line 211, in mavlink_thread_in
    fn(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 1370, in listener
    raise APIException('No heartbeat in %s seconds, aborting.' %
dronekit.APIException: No heartbeat in 30 seconds, aborting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example2.py", line 20, in <module>
    vehicle =connect(connection_string, wait_ready=True) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 3166, in connect
    vehicle.initialize(rate=rate, heartbeat_timeout=heartbeat_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 2275, in initialize
    raise APIException('Timeout in initializing connection.')
dronekit.APIException: Timeout in initializing connection.
```

Comment: Please review my tag edit . There are two tags from 3D Robotics, dronekit and dronekit-python. I selected the dronekit-python tag, but you can change it to the dronekit tag or use both tags.